# Create a list with data extracted from a list of tuples - type issue

Tags: ocaml

My data is ordered like this:

```
([(x1,y1,z1);(x2,y2,z2);(x3,y3,z3);........;(xn,yn,zn)], e:int)
```

Example: I try to create a list `[x1;x2;x3;....;xn;e]` where a value is found only once.

I began the following code but I encounter an issue with type.

```
    let rec verifie_doublons_liste i liste = match liste with
        | [] -> false
        | head::tail -> i = head || verifie_doublons_liste i tail

    let rec existence_doublon liste = match liste with
        | [] -> false
        | head::tail -> (verifie_doublons_liste head tail) || 
            existence_doublon tail

    let premier_du_triplet (x,y,z) = x
    let deuxieme_du_triplet (x,y,z) = y
    let troisieme_du_triplet (x,y,z) = z

    let rec extract_donnees l = match l with
        | [] -> []
        | (x,y,z)::r -> (extract_donnees r)@@(x::z::[])


    let arrange donnees = match donnees with
        | [],i -> i::[]
        | (x,y,z)::[],i -> x::z::i::[]
        | (x,y,z)::r,i -> (extract_donnees r)@@(x::z::i::[])
```

Comment: error in the code : we read operator @ and not @@.


And following message is returned :

Error: This expression has type 'a list
but an expression was expected of type
int * string * int. Data i try to insert in the new list is all the same type.

Comment: Basically, you want to extract first elements in a list of tuples, and add the e elemnent at the end, Am I right ?

Comment: yes exactly ! i doubt about the right way to proceed

Comment: Do you also want unique elements (I.e. without duplicates)?

Comment: Yes but i wrote functions to make each element unique. I juste have to insert condition to that is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to extract first elements in a list of tuples, and add the e elemnent at the end.

*The easiest way* is to use a List.map to extract the first elements

```
List.map premier_du_triplet
```

is a function that will take a list of 3-tuples and extract the first element of each.

then you can add the e element at the end using the "@" operator.

*The more efficient and informative way* would be to directly write a recursive function, say *f* that does just what you want.

When writing a recursive function, you need to ask yourself two things

- what does it do in the simplest case (here, what does f [] do ?)
- when you have a list in format head::tail, and you can already use f on the tail, what should you do to head and tail to obtain (f (head::tail)) ?

With this information, you should be able to write a recursive function that does what you want using pattern matching

here the simplest case is

```
| [] -> [e]
```

(you just add e at the end)

and the general case is

```
| h::t -> (premier_de_triplet h)::(f t)
```